# Netherlands: Passing grades for the integration exams

Tags: citizenship, netherlands

In the Netherlands as part of the naturalization process, one must pass the following exams individually.

- Reading (Around 25 questions)
- Writing (Around 7-8 questions)
- Speaking (Around 24 questions)
- Listening (Around 25 questions)
- Knowledge of Dutch Society (Around 43 questions)
- Orientation on the Dutch Labour Market (It's not really an exam, but a proces, rather cringing...)

However, as much as I've searched for an answer, I haven't been able to find any official statement on what the passing grades (in percentages or number of correct answers, etc.. ) for these exams.

Per exam, what are the minimum passing grades?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From wetten.overheid.nl (Government laws):

[Examenreglement basisexamen inburgering](https://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0019569/2017-10-01):

> De uitslag wordt per afgelegd examenonderdeel uitgedrukt in een cijfer op de schaal van 1 tot 10. Een deelnemer moet een voldoende behalen (6 of hoger) om te slagen voor het examenonderdeel. Een deelnemer is geslaagd voor het basisexamen wanneer hij voor alle drie examenonderdelen een voldoende heeft behaald.

Google translation:

> The result will be expressed per exam part in a grade on the scale of 1 to 10. A participant must score sufficient (6 or higher) in order to pass the exam component. A participant has passed the basic exam when he has passed a satisfactory mark for all three exam components.

That is the usual threshold for grading in The Netherlands: a 6 is *sufficient*, a 5 is *insufficient*.

This does not tell you anything about how individual answers or exam parts are scored. I was unable to find anything, but that does not surprise me; in order to prevent objections and appeals about details I assume this information is not divulged.

Comment: Looking at the text of the law, it talks about 3 exams. But they currently have 5 exams... Isn’t that a bit weird? :)

Comment: They talk about 3 exam *parts*, If you follow the link in paragraph 1a, [artikel 3.98a, eerste lid, van het Vreemdelingenbesluit 2000](https://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0011825/2018-09-19#Hoofdstuk3_Afdeling4_Paragraaf1_Artikel3.98a) these seem to be mentioned in Artikel 3.98a, section 3a: leesvaardigheid, luistervaardigheid, spreekvaardigheid (reading skills, listening comprehension, speaking skills). I *think* that covers the first 4 parts mentioned in the question. Which leaves the question where those 6(5) parts in the question come from exactly, but that's stuff I cannot answer.

Comment: Note that these exams have a complicated history and structure. Are you talking about the 'Integration examination' mentioned [here](https://www.nt2.nl/en/dossier/kennis_nederlandse_maatschappij/wat_is_knm)?

Comment: Based on my exerience, you take the full exam and may pass certain parts and fail others. Then, you have another chance to pass again those that you failed. Not sure how many attempts you have overall.

Comment: @Jan Doggen, I’m talking about the 6 mentioned here https://www.inburgeren.nl/examen-doen/index.jsp